# Creating a raster image from a NumPy array

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, arcgis, arcpy

I am scripting using arcpy, and I have a NumPy matrix with dimensions crops by counties. This matrix is populated with floats.

I also have an individual raster image showing crops as well as a shapefile showing counties.

I would like to save the contents of my NumPy matrix to a new raster, using the correct value in the matrix given that the raster pixel is a certain crop in a certain county.

My question is: how can I improve the way that I'm converting the matrix to a raster image?

Currently I do something like the following:

```
# initialize my output
outraster = 0 * cropraster

for crop in crops
    for county in counties
        outraster = outraster + \
        conditional statements checking if cropraster pixel is in 
        current county and crop, and if so return matrix value

outraster.save(filename)
```

The conditional statements are nested spatial analyst "Con" calls, whose syntax I will spare you.

This works OK, but is quite ugly and I feel there should be a better way to do what I'm trying to do. The above approach crashes when I attempt too many counties or crops. It fails on the save step.

I would like to know if there is a simpler way to accomplish what I'm after. Any advice?

Comment: You need to explore arcpy more. Numpy array access ... to and from .. is built in and used extensively. Begin with this link then explore the rest of the options in the data access module [NumPyArrayToRaster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/numpyarraytoraster-function.htm)

Comment: Thank you for the response @DanPatterson. I realize that in skimming my post, everything about it suggests that I'm looking for the functionality that NumPyArrayToRaster provides (the title virtually screams it!). In reality I'm trying to do something pretty different and more complicated, which is to use information in an array to populate a raster. I think with arcpy the above approach is probably the best that can be done, but that I should look into other software for a more efficient approach.

Answer (score 0):

[NumPyArrayToRaster (arcpy)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/NumPyArrayToRaster/03q30000007q000000/) was designed for this type of operation.

An example from the documentation:

```
import arcpy
import numpy

# Create a simple array from scratch using random values
myArray = numpy.random.random_integers(0,100,2500)
myArray.shape = (50,50)

# Convert array to a geodatabase raster
myRaster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(myArray,x_cell_size=1)
myRaster.save("C:/output/fgdb.gdb/myRandomRaster")
```

Comment: do you know how to do it using Pyqgis ? (qgis.core)